# Showing a view relative to a button android

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I accomplish something like this as shown in the image below:

[image]

So what I want is once I make a click or long one on any of the button I want to show a layout contaning few buttons at the top of the button that is click on.

I have the following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="3">

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="showme"
            android:id="@+id/button36"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="showme"
            android:id="@+id/button37"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="showme"
            android:id="@+id/button38"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="clickme"
            android:id="@+id/button39"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="clickme"
            android:id="@+id/button40"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="clickme"
            android:id="@+id/button41"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="clickme"
            android:id="@+id/button42"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weightSum="4" >

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="clickme"
            android:id="@+id/button43"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="clickme"
            android:id="@+id/button44"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="clickme"
            android:id="@+id/button45"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="clickme"
            android:id="@+id/button46"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Which gives me the following result:
[image]

So basically I have the first linearlayout containings the buttons named 'showme' which I want to show at relative to the top position of any button I click from the last two linearlayout named 'clickme'.

I think I should do it in java code but I just can't figure out how to accomplish it first in xml layout.

Answer (score 0):

I hope 
      this will works for you.Here is the source also.
              [popup menu](http://www.javatpoint.com/android-popup-menu-example)

```
// activity_main.xml

<RelativeLayout xmlns:androclass="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="match_parent"  
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"  
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"  
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"  
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"  
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >  

    <Button  
        android:id="@+id/button1"  
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"  
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"  
        android:layout_marginLeft="62dp"  
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"  
        android:text="Show Popup" />  

</RelativeLayout>  

//popupmenu.xml

<menu xmlns:androclass="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >  

    <item  
        android:id="@+id/one"  
        android:title="One"/>  

    <item  
        android:id="@+id/two"  
        android:title="Two"/>  

    <item  
        android:id="@+id/three"  
        android:title="Three"/>  

</menu>  

//MainActivity.java

package com.javatpoint.popupmenu;  
import android.os.Bundle;  
import android.app.Activity;  
import android.view.Menu;  
import android.view.MenuItem;  
import android.view.View;  
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;  
import android.widget.Button;  
import android.widget.PopupMenu;  
import android.widget.Toast;  
public class MainActivity extends Activity {  
Button button1;  

         @Override  
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  

          button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);  
          button1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  

           @Override  
           public void onClick(View v) {  
            //Creating the instance of PopupMenu  
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(MainActivity.this, button1);  
            //Inflating the Popup using xml file  
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());  

            //registering popup with OnMenuItemClickListener  
            popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {  
             public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {  
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
              return true;  
             }  
            });  

            popup.show();//showing popup menu  
           }  
          });//closing the setOnClickListener method  
         }  
    }
```

Comment: @neo as Zahan Safallwa said this is not what i ask for .my problem is in the layout itself not how to setonlongclicklistener

Comment: @Neo the pop up menu are vertically i need them horizentally with my own layout . i figure out how to display them by simply using the x and y position of the button being clicked on and adding the view i want with respect to these positions .thx anyway

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically set the XML styles with selectors

Comment: i don't think selectors have anything to do with my question else please explain more